# PHP/MYSQL Could not display data from MYSQL in Drop Down Box

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having a problem displaying data from MYSQL into drop down box.

Output:

[image]

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name=displayQuestion>
        Survey Categories : 
        <select name="surveyCategory">
        <option> Choose Survey Category </option>
        <?php
            $surveyQuery = "SELECT survey_id, survey_name FROM surveys";
            $result = mysql_query($surveyQuery) or die (mysql_error());
            while($menu=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<option value=$menu[survey_id]>$menu[survey_name]</option>";                  
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, mysql_query has been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. That said, where are you establishing your connection to the db? Add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no reason to use that ugly formatting:

```
echo '<option value="' . $menu['survey_id'] . '">' . $menu['survey_name'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Access field value with simple quotes `$menu['survey_name']`

Comment: Your code have syntax error: `'<option value="'> . ` should be `'<option value="' . `

Answer (score 1):

You need put your option value within quotes and access array with simple quotes like as:

```
echo "<option value=\"$menu['survey_id']\">$menu['survey_name']</option>";
```